# Некорректная работа в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: сеть, firefox, кроссбраузерность

Не первый раз встречаюсь с этой проблемой.
Суть ее вот в чем:
Есть изображение, которое открывается во всех браузерах, кроме Mozilla Firefox. Через консоль, при наведение говорит "не найдено изображение". НО! При клике на ссылку изображение открывается...

Дополнительная информация:
1. Картинка действительно есть на сервере и она не внешняя;
2. Ошибок в консоли нет, только при наведении пишет, что картинка не найдена, но после клика(по ссылке) он ее открывает;
3. Кэш почистил и зашел в режим инкогнито.

Раньше такое встречал(не на этом сайте) в браузере Google Chrome.

Сам ресурс можно увидеть тут [тут](https://www.elglobo.com.pl/), картинка [тут](https://www.elglobo.com.pl/assets/www/img/banner/1.jpg)(она должна работать как popup).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дайте хоть ссылку на картинку

Comment: @gil9red, добавил в описание

Comment: у меня (win7, x64, Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit)) показывает картинку. сайт загружается, появляется впереди та картинка

Comment: @gil9red, хм, может это что-то у меня с браузером.

Comment: @gil9red, добавил картинку

Comment: Интересно, а на вкладке Сеть как эта картинка отображается

Comment: @gil9red, в сети смотрел, ее вообще нет.